# Typescript Node.js Prototype Won't Compile

Tags: node.js, compilation, typescript, firebase

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.
I'd like to extend my Firebase object with a prototype method

However I get:

`Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Firebase'`

```
/// <reference path="./tsd.d.ts"/>
import Firebase = require('firebase');
interface Firebase {
     foo : () => string
}

Firebase.prototype.foo = function(): string {
    return "foo";
}

var myRootRef = new Firebase('myUrl');
firebase.foo() // property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Firebase'.
```

Comment: Have you tried regular class extending? `class MyFirebase extends Firebase { foo(){} }`. Or rather my question is, does it need to be on the Firebase object?

Comment: I'd like to avoid inheritance as much as possible. Interfaces are better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an `import` in your code :

```
import Firebase = require('firebase');
```

your file is now a module and the `interface Firebase {` is disconnected from the global namespace. Move this declaration into a `global.d.ts` file.

More : see modifying native types : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html

Answer (score 2):

I actually solved it. I realized that I needed to `declare` in a `custom.d.ts` that Firebase.

```
/// <reference path="../firebase/firebase.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../rx/rx.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../rx/rx-lite.d.ts"/>

interface Firebase {
     rx_observe : (eventType: string) => Rx.Observable<FirebaseDataSnapshot>
}

declare var fb : Firebase

declare module 'custom' {
     export = fb
}
```

Now I include my prototype declaration.

```
import Firebase = require('firebase');
import Rx = require('rx');

Firebase.prototype.__proto__.rx_observe = function(eventType: string): Rx.Observable<FirebaseDataSnapshot> {
    var self: Firebase = this;
    return Rx.Observable.create<FirebaseDataSnapshot>(observer => {
        var listener = self.on(eventType, (snapshot) => {
             observer.onNext(snapshot);
        })
        return () => {
            self.off(eventType, listener);
        }
    });
}
```